# C - Sorting an year of data by months first then day

Tags: c, algorithm, sorting

I am trying to sort an year worth of records into months first and then by days of the month (1-28/29/30/31) in C. I have sorted by months.

```
struct DailyData {
    int day;
    int month;
    int year;
    float high;
    float low;
    float precipitation;
    char condition;
};

void sortYearData(struct DailyData yearData[], int sizeOfArray){

    int i,j;
    struct DailyData climate;


    for (i = sizeOfArray - 1; i > 0; i--) {
        for (j = 0; j < i; j++) {
            if (yearData[j].month > yearData[j+1].month) {
                climate = yearData[j];
                yearData[j] = yearData[j+1];
                yearData[j+1] = climate;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

I am trying to figure out how to now sort the days within the month.

Any help or advise will be great.

Thank you

Answer (score 4):

There is no need to write your own sort algorithm.

First, write a comparer that compares two items, like this:

```
int data_comparer(void const *x, void const *y) {
    DailyData const *X = x, *Y = y;
    return  X->month != Y->month ? (X->month > Y->month) - (X->month < Y->month)
                                 : (X->day   > Y->day)   - (X->day   < Y->day);
}
```

Then you can use this with `qsort` like so:

```
void sortYearData(struct DailyData yearData[], size_t sizeOfArray){
    qsort(yearData, sizeOfArray, sizeof *yearData, data_comparer);
}
```

As a caveat, you can use the same comparer for `bsearch`:

```
struct DailyData *search(struct DailyData yearData[], size_t sizeOfArray, struct DailyData *search_query) {
    return bsearch(search_query, yearData, sizeOfArray, sizeof *yearData, data_comparer);
}
```

Answer (score 3):

Couldn't you just change your if condition to:

```
if ((yearData[j].month > yearData[j+1].month) || 
    ((yearData[j].month == yearData[j+1].month) &&
     (yearData[j].day > yearData[j+1].day)))
{
```